# How to extend a Xul button and make it focusable?

Tags: javascript, xul, xbl

When I extends this button in my XBL:

```
<binding id="myFancyButton" extends="chrome://global/content/bindings/button.xml#button">
```

how do I make it a **focusable** button?

Comment: I found the wikipedia link for XBL (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XBL), but I'm a bit unclear what you're working on. Is this for a desktop application? I'm curious, thanks.

Comment: @calvinf yes, it's a desktop app in Xul.

Comment: You might want to tag this as XUL. The XUL category has 315 posts vs. XBL which has 6.  More likely to find somebody with an answer that way.

Answer (score 0):

As I am not sure what you have in your button.xml,

I can only really provide this link and ask you to make sure your button follows the guidelines here: https://wiki.mozilla.org/XUL:Focus_Behaviour

Especially the bit about the -moz-user-focus property is important.

Edited: this is a simple hello world example, the button is focusable.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://global/skin/" type="text/css"?>
<window id="main" title="My App" width="300" height="300" xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">
  <button label="Hello World" oncommand="alert('You pressed me')" style="max-width: 100px"/>
</window>
```

Comment: The [button.xml](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla/source/toolkit/content/widgets/button.xml) is built in. And *"The -moz-user-focus CSS property is obsolete and does nothing (or for compatibility, the value 'ignore' is treated as focusable='false' and the value 'normal' is treated as focusable='auto')"*. Still I tested, with no success.

Comment: IF this the default button, it should be focusable by default.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with that binding ? Why would you not just use the regular button tag ?

Comment: I'm just would like to understand the extends mechanism and how the button works. My button still has no focus capability, I may be doing something wrong..

Comment: Added an example with a button. You can use 'style' to change the button anyway you want.